# Not able to read the data from the MIC

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to read the data from the MIC and process it and store it in a file. But i am not getting any data from the MIC, the buffer is all zeroes.

```
int MIN_BUF = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(
        MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, MIN_BUF);
byte[] pcm_in = new byte[320];

recorder.startRecording();

while(record)
{
    int bytes_read = recorder.read(pcm_in, 0, pcm_in.length);

    switch(bytes_read)
    {
    case AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION:
    case AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE:                   
        Log.i("Microphone", "Error in reading the data");
        break;
    default:
        print(pcm_in);
        break;
    }
}

recorder.stop();
recorder.release();
```

But in the print(pcm), when i printed byte by byte i am getting all zeroes. Some posts are there in stackoverflow with similar issues, but my issue didn't got fixed with that.

Please help me in fixing this.

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

Comment: Did you make sure you have the:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes i have used that permission

Answer (score 0):

print(pcm_in) will show you the actual data. you need to get the pcm_in data to pcm in a loop till you stop recording.

Meaning that your variable record is a boolean right. and you will make it false in another method. so till you make it false recorder.read(pcm_in, 0, pcm_in.length) operation will get the data from your mic and put it into the pcm_in(so you need to be sure that the size of pcm_in is equal to pcm). the bytes_read will be the size of the bytes read in this operation. so you can copy the pcm_in bytes to pcm in a loop that can read whole pcm_in data.

for example:

```
bytes_read = recorder.read(pcm_in, 0, pcm_in.length);

for(int i=0; i<bytes_read ;i++){
        pcm[i] = pcm_in[i];
 }
```

But this is a weird usage. I think your pcm should be as large as the file you need to load in it. and make sure you are addin the pcm_in to it , not overriding. I think this is what you want.

Comment: I am very sorry, actually i mean pcm_in only, pcm_in is member variable. So for pasting here i edited the function. Please let me know if any problem in the code.

Comment: first of all you get the MIN_BUF use this value for the buffer size like byte[] pcm_in = new byte[MIN_BUF] 
then make sure to present the print(byte[] pcm) correctly. 
try debugging with a real device and using break points. It seems there is nothing wrong in your code. it could be more helpful if you can paste the print function code as well.